# To import all objects in multiple nested foreign key relationships efficiently in django

Tags: django, orm

### Is there an effective way to get all dictionary objects that correspond to the product?

#### This is my django model

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    product = FK(Product)
    middle = FK(Middle)
    ...

class Middle(models.Model):
    dictionary = FK(Dictionary)
    ...

class Dictionary(models.Model):
    ...
```

The way I did it.

```py
product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
ingredients = ProductIngredient.objects.filter(product=product)
middles = ProductMiddle.objects.filter(ingredient__in=ingredients)
dictionaries = ProductDictionary.objects.filter(middle__in=middles)
```

but I want

```py
dictionaries = product.ingredient.middle.dictionary.all() (?)
# AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'middle'
```

Or
Is there a better way?

Is there a way to import this data with fewer queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

`dictionaries = Dictionary.objects.filter(middle__ingredient__product_id=1)`

The names could be wrong, depending on the `related_name` you defined on each FK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's been a great help!